# Display attribute set groups with product

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I need to display groups with attributes when I display product informations.

For example, I have an attribute set with there informations :

> Group 1 : Attribute1 Attribute2
>
> Group 2 : Attribute1 Attribute2

I like to display all attributes and also the group's name in the product.

Answer (score 1):

The same question was answered on [SO, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438750/how-to-display-attribute-group-name-on-product-page).
The main idea is to create a block similar to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes`.
The difference is that, in your new block, the attributes are grouped by the `group_id`.
You also need a template similar to `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` (or you can use that one) where you can arrange the data from the block as you want.

Comment: I used magento 1.7 in this question he used 1.5 version

Comment: @Amirov But did you try the same approach on 1.7/ You will be surprised. It might work.

Comment: But All files are different. For exemple i don't have this file in magento 1.7 /app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_TEMPLATE/layout/catalog.xml

Comment: Actually there should be. Maybe in a different form. Read how themes work in Magento: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/

Comment: Thanks i found this file and i add all files but doesn't work with my template :(